# Test-Train Split: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 120 +

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Performing a test-train split in Python.

```
columns=['columns of interest']
X = df[columns]
y = df['Response_Variable']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=12345)
```

Consequently, trying to use sklearn's DecisionTreeRegressor

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
treereg = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=1)
treereg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When running my code, I keep getting a ValueError. I know this is attributed to my datatypes being inconsistent, but would appreciate some clarification on converting my columns (signified by X -- mixture of objects and integers) to produce my desired regression. Thanks.

Comment: Can't tell from the code you've posted but it looks like you're trying to pass an invalid string to be converted to a float.

Comment: Can you post the `df.info()` for `df[columns]` and `y`, they need to be numeric